# Include OCR Api in a C project

Tags: c, api, ocr

Hi all i'm at computer science (bd),for my exam project i want to make a c ocr program (no gui),i search in the internet for tesseract but i don't find any api for c but only for c++,anyone knows a ocr api for c language?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of using Tesseract C API, taken from the [official documentation](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/APIExample#Example_using_the_C-API_in_a_C_program):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <allheaders.h>
#include <capi.h>

void die(const char *errstr) {
        fputs(errstr, stderr);
        exit(1);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        TessBaseAPI *handle;
        PIX *img;
        char *text;

        if((img = pixRead("img.png")) == NULL)
                die("Error reading image\n");

        handle = TessBaseAPICreate();
        if(TessBaseAPIInit3(handle, NULL, "eng") != 0)
                die("Error initialising tesseract\n");

        TessBaseAPISetImage2(handle, img);
        if(TessBaseAPIRecognize(handle, NULL) != 0)
                die("Error in Tesseract recognition\n");

        if((text = TessBaseAPIGetUTF8Text(handle)) == NULL)
                die("Error getting text\n");

        fputs(text, stdout);

        TessDeleteText(text);
        TessBaseAPIEnd(handle);
        TessBaseAPIDelete(handle);
        pixDestroy(&img);

        return 0;
}
```

If you are using Linux, you can [compile it as you would compile a program using C++ API](https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/APIExample#Compiling_C++_API_programs_on_Linux).